# How do I remove publications from Marketing Cloud's subscription center?

Tags: marketing-cloud

There are outdated publication lists showing within my subscription center - how do I remove these?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'outdated'?

Comment: We have publication lists listed in our subscription center that we are no longer sending to (ex. a specific monthly newsletter that is no longer being sent out)

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by the Publication List setting *Public* which you can turn on/off.

If set as Public then it will be displayed on the standard Subscription Center.

- [**Publication Lists in SFMC**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_publication_list.htm&type=5) (step 6)

[image: PublicOrNot]